# Function swipeleft / swiperight

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on("swiperight", function(event, ui){
    $("#mypanel, #mypanel2, #mypanel3, #mypanel4, #mypanel5").panel("open");
});

$(document).on("swipeleft", function(event, ui){
    $("#mypanel, #mypanel2, #mypanel3, #mypanel4, #mypanel5").panel("close");
});
```

I'm new to jQuery and javascript. I was trying to do a `swipeleft` / `swiperight` on my panels.
The thing is the swipe event only applies on the first page/panel. The panels on the other pages don't respond.

Here's the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDdyM/). Could anyone help me understand why this is not working as expected?

Comment: You have some errors in your JSFiddle, I've updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDdyM/1/). Don't use script-tags in the JavaScript area and use normal (double) quotes in your HTML (`data-dismissible="true"` was using odd quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use an *external* panel (one panel for all pages) that can be accessed from any page, less HTML tags and faster page processing.

   - HTML

     ```
     <!-- External panel -->
     <div data-role="panel" id="external">
     </div>  

     <!-- Pages -->
     <div data-role="page" id="page1">
     </div>

     <div data-role="page" id="page2">
     </div>
     ```
   - JS: Initialize *external panel* and add `swipe` listener.

     ```
     $(function () {
       $("[data-role=panel]").enhanceWithin().panel();
     });

     $(document).on("swiperight", function (event, ui) {
       $("#external").panel("open");
     });
     ```
2. Open panel of current/active page, if you decide to use a separate panel for each page.

   ```
   $(document).on("swiperight", function (event, ui) {
     $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").find("[data-role=panel]").panel("open");
   });
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SCx33/)**

Comment: sorry you answered my problem but it appears that the external panel doesn't go with the height of the device. If I am having a scrolling page, the panel's height doesn't occupy the whole page. I tried min-height and max-height to 100% still doesnt work.

Comment: @user3143341 add `data-position-fixed="true"` to panel div.